# Dataframe.plot - remove time from x axis, keeping the date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove the time from x axis with `Dataframe.plot`?

This is my code:

```
data.reset_index().plot(x='Date', y='Open', kind = 'bar', colormap='gist_rainbow')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: OP precised that the question was about formatting and not removing dates.

Use matplotlib directly instead of pandas.

Reference: [matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", freq="MS", periods=6),
    "A": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "B": [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar("Date", "B", data=df, axes=ax, width=5)  # Set width for larger bars
dfmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d") # proper formatting Year-month-day
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt)
ax.set_xlabel("Date")  # Naming the x-axis
plt.xticks(rotation=45) # Optionam but helps when dates are long
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to remove 00:00:00, keeping the date on x-axis.

Comment: @APAL I edited my post to answer your question, please do accept the answer if this is the fix you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the calendar dates are the index of your DataFrame, you can do an easy hack by rewriting the index to only contain information about the Date, and discarding the information about Time:

```
data.index = data.index.date
```

For more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html